# Insert more fields onclick using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a web application that gives user the chance to input more names as user wishes. the form has a link that has to perform an addition of textboxes on click of that link. 
i know there is a way to use jquery to do that but currently don't know why cos i just moved to jquery from angularjs

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <table width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><div align="right"><strong><a href="#">Add More Fields</a></strong></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Address</td>
          <td>Age</td>
          <td>Phone Number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to identify better your elements. Let's put an id for **table**, an id for **add more fields link** and a class for **tr model**.

Then we have to copy all html you want to duplicate.
Then append it to table.

Remember that doing this, when you submit, all those duplicate parameters will become an array of values.

Let's refactor some bad code here too.

Since we are duplicating fields we need to remove Id attribute of them all.

I'm moving add link outside the table and removing those blank tds. Also write a good table with `thead` and `tbody`.

When we want to add field, we want to remove too. So let's create a link to remove.

```js
function cloneTrModel() {
  return $('.model').first().clone();
}

var trModel = cloneTrModel();

function setRemove() {
  $(".remove" ).click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  });
}

setRemove();

$( "#add" ).click(function() {
  $("#contactTable tbody").append(trModel);
  trModel = cloneTrModel();
  setRemove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<strong style="float: right;"><a href="#" id="add">Add More Fields</a></strong>
  <table id="contactTable" width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="model">
      <td class="inner"><input type="text" name="name[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="age[]"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="phone_number[]"></td>
      <td><a href="javascript:;" class="remove">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: when i click can i get an increment to the ids and the names of each textbox

Comment: Yes it's possible. However it's not a good thing to do what you are thinking. The right way is transform every field's name to an array. name="address[]" for example

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function()
  {
      $('a').click(function(){
          var id=$(':text').length;
          $('#field').append('<td>Textbox'+id+'</td>');
          $('#more').append('<td><input type="text" id='+id+' name="text'+id+'"></td>');
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <table width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><div align="right"><strong><a href="#">Add More Fields</a></strong></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="field">
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Address</td>
          <td>Age</td>
          <td>Phone Number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="more">
          <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

or try this one

```js
$(document).ready(function()
  {
      $('a').click(function(){
          var id=$(':text').length;
          $('#more td').append('<input type="text" id='+id+' name="text'+id+'">');
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  input{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
</style>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <table width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><div align="right"><strong><a href="#">Add More Fields</a></strong></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="field">
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Address</td>
          <td>Age</td>
          <td>Phone Number</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="more">
          <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: i just tried but when it adds and i check the id's of the textfield, its all the same, but i was thinking i get eg. name2 and on next click name4 etc

Comment: because i will be inserting into the database so each has to be unique

Comment: all field you have want textbox or only name field textbox @user6579134

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```js
$( "#add" ).click(function() {
$( ".inner" ).append( "<input type='text' name='name' id='name'>" );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><div align="right"><strong><a href="#" id="add">Add More Fields</a></strong></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>Phone Number</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="inner"><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="phone_number" id="phone_number"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```